# Formatting Date in DatePicker, Storing Date in Database

Tags: android, datetime, formatting, datepicker

I am fetching a Date from a `DatePicker` which formats it depending on the user location (I think). I would like to format this Date so the user can choose a format.

Also I want to store this date to a Database. For later usage I'd like to use the format `yyyyMMdd`.

My problem right now is still with  the `DatePicker` formatting my Date.

This is what I have written right now:

```
 public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, OnClickListener {


        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker


            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {


            // Do something with the date chosen by the user

                dateValue = String.valueOf("" + day + "." + (month + 1) + "." + year);
                date_widget.setText(dateValue);



            try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdfToDate = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyyMdd");

                dateDB = String.valueOf(sdfToDate.parse(dateValue));
                Log.e("Date", dateDB);
            } catch (ParseException ex2) {
                ex2.printStackTrace();

            }





        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
```

I don't think this is the best way to do this but the `DatePicker` works.

Since my month has only 1 digit i get an exception when trying to format my dateValue:

```
 Unparseable date: "22.6.2013" (at offset 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a date in onDateSet method with Calendar class, then format in your way.

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) 
{
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(year,month,day);

            Date date = calendar.getTime();
}
```

Comment: I need to format the date which the user picks. How can this help me with that?

Comment: If have a date, formatting is too easy... Check this..http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @mike.b93 You can store that `date` object somewhere in your code and then format it as you want for whatever use you need, like showing it to the user or store it on a database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change format of **dateValue** to **yyyyMMdd** and then try to parse.

Comment: I wanna show `dateValue` in my button as `ddMMyyyy` but save it as `yyyyMMdd` to the database. I have actually no idea how to parse this properly.

I edited my code slightly

Answer (score 0):

when you parsing the string as date remove "." from string.

Comment: Will do, but can't really parse with the given error above. int month is only one digit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

`String date = "22.6.2013";`
`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.M.yyyy");`
`Date date1 = sdf.parse(date);`

`System.out.println("Formatted Date  : "+date1);`

`sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMdd");`
`System.out.println("Final Format : "+sdf.format(date1));`

Comment: this would still give me only 1 digit for month. This wouldn't let me compare dates later on. BTW: You don't need to add an answer every time. You can just comment...

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")

String formattedDate = sdf.format(view.getCalendarView().getDate());

Comment: I need to format the date which the user picks with the `DatePicker` I don't think this would help me with that